# how do I decode an anonymous event?

Tags: events, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm trying to decode a simple anonymous event I wrote in my contract and instead of result I'm getting an empty array, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using hardhat.

contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
contract Lock {

   event DataStored(address admin, uint256 indexed data) anonymous;
   uint256 data;
   function storeData(uint256 data) external {
      data = data;
      emit DataStored(msg.sender, data);

   }
}
```

deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");
const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/Lock.sol/Lock.json");
const abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder');

async function main() {
  

  const Lock = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Lock");
  const lock = await Lock.deploy();

  await lock.deployed();

  console.log(
    ` deployed to ${lock.address}`
  );
  tx = await lock.storeData(10);
  const transactionReceipt = await tx.wait()
  abiDecoder.addABI(contract.abi);
  const decodedLogs = abiDecoder.decodeLogs(transactionReceipt.events);
  console.log(transactionReceipt.events)
  console.log(decodedLogs);


}
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

and the result I'm getting from running the deploy.js

```
deployed to 0x21dF544947ba3E8b3c32561399E88B52Dc8b2823
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think you should try to learn the different between non-anonymous and anonymous event by this example

smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Lock {

    event DataStoredNonAnonymous(address admin, uint256 indexed data);
    event DataStoredAnonymous(address admin, uint256 indexed data) anonymous;
   
    uint256 x;
    uint256 y;
   
    function storeDataNonAnonymous(uint256 _data) external {
      x = _data;
      emit DataStoredNonAnonymous(msg.sender, _data);
    }

    function storeDataAnonymous(uint256 _data) external {
      y = _data;
      emit DataStoredAnonymous(msg.sender, _data);
    }

}
```

deploy.js or deploy.ts depending on your preference

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
  const Lock = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lock");
  const lock = await Lock.deploy();

  await lock.deployed();

  console.log(`deployed to ${lock.address}`);
  const tx1 = await lock.storeDataNonAnonymous(10);
  const txReceipt1 = await tx1.wait()
  console.log("event non-anonymous",txReceipt1.events)

  const tx2 = await lock.storeDataAnonymous(12345);
  const txReceipt2 = await tx2.wait()
  console.log("event anonymous",txReceipt2.events)

}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

The result after deployed on the terminal the topic[0] which is reserved for specify the event signature will not showing up

```
Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully
deployed to 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
event non-anonymous [
  {
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockNumber: 2,
    transactionHash: '0x22e2b2c6274a83e0c6ff9e2733e7875940e038f3faf5641d77ede41958657fa0',
    address: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
    topics: [
      '0xe70463dc16bf49899544f11b2caa7874683dbf886102edb6cbc82d728dc425d4',
      '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a'
    ],
    data: '0x000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266',
    logIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x1491b08df4abb9ac8aaeb3be796ab0635957668224470944fd215400a02ce276',
    args: [
      '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
      BigNumber { value: "10" },
      admin: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
      data: BigNumber { value: "10" }
    ],
    decode: [Function (anonymous)],
    event: 'DataStoredNonAnonymous',
    eventSignature: 'DataStoredNonAnonymous(address,uint256)',
    removeListener: [Function (anonymous)],
    getBlock: [Function (anonymous)],
    getTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    getTransactionReceipt: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
event anonymous [
  {
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockNumber: 3,
    transactionHash: '0x76ec1eef5693031441fd0446ab681d3f703cca3a016167b343ad8d75fdfd478f',
    address: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
    topics: [
      '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003039'
    ],
    data: '0x000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266',
    logIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0xd4f64019225eb982522f8f41a1cc2d6869a7ac41f5d93e5b6f7fb39607914e78',
    removeListener: [Function (anonymous)],
    getBlock: [Function (anonymous)],
    getTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
    getTransactionReceipt: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
```